# Accidently deleted header files in /usr/include/c++

Tags: 12.04, c++, g++

I accidently deleted the folder with all the C++ header files that resides in /usr/include/c++. What do I do to recover the

UPDATE I did get the header files back now in /usr/include/c++.
However, even a simple C++ Hello World Program is giving me this error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/localefwd.h:42:0,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ios:42,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.6/ostream:40,
             from /usr/include/c++/4.6/iostream:40,
             from Hello.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:53:23: error: ‘uselocale’     was not declared in this scope
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:53:45: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h: In function ‘int std::__convert_from_v(__locale_struct* const&, char*, int, const char*, ...)’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:76:53: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__uselocale’ cannot be used as a function
/usr/include/c++/4.6/x86_64-linux-gnu/./bits/c++locale.h:101:33: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__uselocale’ cannot be used as a function
```

Answer (score 4):

You can get a comma separated list of packages that have installed files to /usr/include/c++ with

```
dpkg --search /usr/include/c++
```

and then run for each listed package

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall
```

Comment: I got the folders back.. But im getting a new error

Comment: Is is possible that also something from /usr/include got deleted, not only /usr/include/c++?

Comment: I havent deleted anything for usr/include manually, but it could be possible... Its come to the state before I deleted the folder - where c++  code wasnt successfully getting compiled.. Read the question agai - i updated it to show the latest error

Comment: do I do the same thing for /usr/include that i did for /usr/include/c++ ??

Comment: No, it's better to figure out if something is actually missing instead of forcing everything in, especially considering /usr/include is used by many packages. You can verify the files with first installing a support tool `sudo apt-get install debsums` and then checking all packages that use /usr/include with `debsums -s $(dpkg --search /usr/include | cut -d: -f1 | sed 's:,::g')`. That command will give output only in case of something is missing.

Comment: it didnt return anything

Comment: saved my life :)

Answer (score 0):

try reinstalling g++

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall g++
```

Comment: It reinstalled.. But still getting iostream missing error.Header files still missing

Comment: AFAIK `g++` is only a metapackage that depends on the default `g++-4.x` for your system. You will likely need to re-install the actual corresponding `libstdc++xxx-dev` development package. For 12.04 (default `g++-4.6`) I *think* that's `libstdc++6-4.6-dev`, but you might want to check first using something like `dpkg -l | grep 'libstdc.*-dev'`

Comment: I got the header files back.. But im getting some new error.. read the question again - ive explained it